# How could I clean up messy css-inlined view with helper-methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, responsive-design, actionmailer, erb

I'm using [this email template](https://github.com/mailgun/transactional-email-templates/blob/master/templates/inlined/action.html) in my mailer view, to make it responsive.

The problem is that it's visually very intimidating to work with.

How could I "stuff away" visually complex code (the html) like the following in helper methods:

```
    <table class="main" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 3px; background: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">
      <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <td class="content-wrap" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
              <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                Please confirm your email address by clicking the link below.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
              <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                We may need to send you critical information about our service and it is important that we have an accurate email address.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
              <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                <a href="http://www.mailgun.com" class="btn-primary" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background: #348eda; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-color: #348eda; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;">Confirm email address</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
              <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                &mdash; The Mailgunners
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is there a reason to not use a css file?  is there that much of a performance improvement?

Comment: @dax When styling (responsive) emails, unfortunately the css has to be inlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place to start:

Switch from ERB to [HAML](http://haml.info/), that would instantly cut this in half, and increase the readability of what remains.

Another thing to try could be making variables at the top of your file - I see this being used a lot:

```
table_base = width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 

base_style = style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px;"
```

perhaps you could put that into a variable called 'table_base' or something and then interpolate that into the inline css.  it wouldn't remove all of the inline-ness, but it would clear much of it out.

for example:

```
%table.main "#{table_base} #{base_style}" style="border-radius: 3px; background: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"
```

the interpolation might need some fiddling with, but it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use helper methods. Just use style tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
  table{
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  table.main{
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  }

  table > tr{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  table.main td.content-wrap{
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  table.main table td.content-block{
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
  }

  table.main table td.content-block a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background: #348eda;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-color: #348eda;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 20px;
  }

</style>

<table class="main">
  <tr>
    <td class="content-wrap">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="content-block">
            Please confirm your email address by clicking the link below.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="content-block">
            We may need to send you critical information about our service and it is important that we have an accurate email address.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="content-block">
            <a href="http://www.mailgun.com" class="btn-primary">Confirm email address</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="content-block">
            &mdash; The Mailgunners
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To have responsive emails, unfortunately you HAVE to have the css inlined. http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/

Comment: I guess only Apple devices support responsive emails. And they support style tag too. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/